# Serializing few columns of DataTable into xml and storing it in a column in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datatable, linq-to-xml

I have a DataTable in code in the following format

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyDataset");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Source", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(String));
        //DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add("ABC",DateTime.UtcNow,"Source1","10","11");
        dt.Rows.Add("CDE", DateTime.UtcNow, "Source2", "4", "5");
        dt.Rows.Add("FGH", DateTime.UtcNow, "Source1", "", "");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

That is the table has 3 permanent columns 'Name','Date' and 'Source' and multiple field columns which can change on runtime and table with more columns can be created.

I need to store the above DataTable in DB in a table like

```
ColumnName  Name  |Date    |Source|Fields
Type of     string|DateTime|String|XML
```

How can I serialize the field columns efficiently and send it through stored procedure for saving in database for multiple names and date at a time.

Also I need to have a cache for the above table in code so that we can access the data fast. I am thinking of using

```
Dictionary< Name +Date+Source,< Dictionary< fieldName,fieldValue>>
```

Can you suggest methods to achieve the above

Comment: What if you convert your dataTable into XML and then pass it to Stored Procedure in parameter. Now the type of that parameter either **varchar(max)** or **XML**, its up to you. If you pass it in varchar then in SP you have to convert it into XML data type and then read the XML and fetch the tag value and insert to your table as per the requirement in your SP. you can convert content of dataTable into XML by using **WriteXml()** method of DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WriteXml method of the datatable to get the corresponding XML from it, then Use XPath either on the App layer and pass the three columns as parameters to the sp, or in the stored procedure use XPath to get the three columns from the XML, delete them, and sabe the rest in a XML field to remove Name, Date, Source from the XML (Dont sabe the same data twice).

Now for the cache thing.. Dictionary will be good if thats for now a very large amount of data (consider only taking there those that are frecuently accesed) or try the chache block from Entrerprice library.